# Python 3.4 - Cannot import module

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, bisect

I want to use the bisect module but i get this error 
when i try to `import bisect`:

```
NameError: global name 'bisect_left' is not defined
```

And this error when i try `from bisect import bisect_left`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name bisect_left
```

I'm try to use this function from the python docs:

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    else:
        return False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could not replicate - works fine for me in `3.4.0` on OS X. Could you provide more information about your installation?

Comment: I have the latest python 3 release - 3.4.2 from python.org.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I could replicate it just fine. The OP named their script `bisect.py`.

Comment: **Always** include the full traceback, it eliminates a lot of guesswork. The full traceback would have made it immediately obvious that you named your script `bisect.py`, because you'd see `File "bisect.py", line 1, in <module>` just above the `import bisect` line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named your script `bisect.py`; it is being imported instead of the standard library:

```
nidhogg:stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ cat bisect.py 
import bisect

bisect.bisect_left
nidhogg:stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ bin/python bisect.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bisect.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bisect
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/bisect.py", line 3, in <module>
    bisect.bisect_left
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bisect_left'
nidhogg:stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ echo 'from bisect import bisect_left' > bisect.py
nidhogg:stackoverflow-3.4 mj$ bin/python bisect.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bisect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bisect import bisect_left
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/bisect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bisect import bisect_left
ImportError: cannot import name 'bisect_left'
```

Rename the script so as not to mask it.